# Почему тип дженрика нужно указывать второй раз при использовании {{}}?

Tags: java

Почему так можно:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList</*здесь второй раз Integer указывать уже не надо*/>();
```

А так нельзя:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList</*a здесь почему-то надо*/>(){{
   add(0);
}};
```

Почему так сделали?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22201175/2908793 (я, правда, за одно прочтение так ничего и не понял)

Comment: @Etki ну вообщем там спрашивается тоже, что и здесь. Спасибо

Comment: там не то что спрашивается, там ответ дается

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя так называемый double-brace initialization, вы создаёте новый анонимный класс. Когда в Java-7 разрешили опускать аргументы типа в некоторых случаях, одним из исключений, [явно прописанным в стандарте](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), являются как раз анонимные классы:

> It is a compile-time error if a class instance creation expression declares an anonymous class using the `"<>"` form for the class's type arguments.

Тут нет каких-то принципиальных ограничений, просто усложняло вывод типов в компиляторе, потому что есть много частных случаев. Поэтому недоделали. В Java-9 планируют исправить этот момент — смотрите баг [JDK-8073593](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073593).

В заключение скажу, что double-brace initialization — исключительно дурацкий способ инициализации объектов. У него могут быть неожиданные проблемы: от случайного захвата контекста внешнего класса до смены `serialVersionID`. В вашем случае это вообще не нужно. Пишите так:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0));
```

А если не собираетесь в будущем добавлять и удалять элементы в список, то лучше так:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0);
```

Но даже если б у вас была `Map`, лучше заведите отдельный метод, фабрику или билдер, который создаёт предопределённые `Map`, но не делайте double-brace initialization.

В той же девятке, кстати, планируется упростить этот момент — смотрите [JDK-8048330](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048330). Будет можно писать

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4);
Set<String> set = Set.of("aa", "bb", "cc");
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("aa", 1, "bb", 2, "cc", 3);
```